# Javascript console.log not getting executed?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing an app in Nativescript, and have the following function triggered on my login with Facebook button press. I am not getting the `"ID: " + id` bit printing to my console. Please see below:

```
export function onLoginTap(args) {
    console.log("tap");
    ai.busy = true;
    client.login("Facebook").then((user) => {
        ai.busy = false;
        console.log("Logged In!");
        var id = user.mUserId;
        console.log("ID: " + id); // <- Not Working
    }, (e) => {
        ai.busy = false;

        console.log("Error Logging in!", e);
    });
}
```

When I run this in the debugger, I set a breakpoint on the line where `id` is set, which when it is hit `id` is undefined (although I think this usually happens after the line). I then have a breakpoint on the `console.log` line, but it is never hit... The app continues without throwing any issues and I can click the button again and the same behaviour is repeated.

Any idea what's wrong?

## Update:

In the debugger window (I am using VSCode), user shows up, with the properties I was expecting, including `mUserId`, which equals a string value. If I type `user.mUserId` into the debugging console, and it returns the correct value...

Comment: Try `console.log(user.mUserId)` before assignment to `id`

Comment: Only idea, that when you call user.mUserId "user" is undefined so a property error stops the script.

Comment: What is the value of `this` inside your function? If it's not `window`, then you might try `window.console.log()`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao That doesn't print either ... but if I type `user.mUserId` into the debug console, it returns a string I was expecting??

Comment: @4castle I'll check. but the `console.log("Logged In!");` is working fine

Comment: Maybe some filter is set in your console?) Im spent a lot of time one day, thinkin, why errors are not shown)

Comment: If it's not `console.log()` that's broken, it is probably `user` is not being set to what you expect in that parameter. Try outputting `user` within that function.

Comment: @4castle if I type `user.mUserId` into the debug console, I get a string returned - as I was expecting...

Comment: @George That doesn't mean that `user` is identical in that function, if `user` is a global, it can still be shadowed by the parameter variable (which may have a different value).

Comment: @4castle adding `window.console...` doesn't change the result. The debugger shows the user value, as having the `mUserId` property and a number of others, all with string values ...

Comment: @DmitryLobov How would I check that?